# fix Oracle SQL CMD line

Tags: sql, oracle, cmd, sqlplus

[image]

Table spills down below. Please show me how to fix it. please

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set the `linesize` setting. The [linesize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#i2678481) setting controls how many characters appear on a single line before it will wrap.

[image: sql command line]

Answer (score 1):

Well, setting the `linesize` just might not be enough - `col` is the savior, as it enables you to set every single column's format so that the output looks nice. Also, for date columns, you might even need to alter the session to set default date format (or use `TO_CHAR` with appropriate format mask).

Here's a demonstration: ugly output:

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum = 1;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
HIREDATE                   SAL       COMM
------------------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902
17.12.1980 00:00:00       1000
        20
```

Set columns' formats:

```
SQL> col empno format 99999
SQL> col ename format a7
SQL> col job format a5
SQL> col mgr format 9999
SQL> col sal format 9999
SQL> col comm format 9999
SQL> col deptno format 999999
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.
```

Let's try again:

```
SQL> select * from emp where rownum < 5;

 EMPNO ENAME   JOB        MGR HIREDATE     SAL  COMM  DEPTNO
------ ------- -------- ----- ---------- ----- ----- -------
  7369 SMITH   CLERK     7902 17.12.1980  1000            20
  7499 ALLEN   SALESMAN  7698 20.02.1981  1600   300      30
  7521 WARD    SALESMAN  7698 22.02.1981  1250   500      30
  7566 JONES   MANAGER   7839 02.04.1981  2975            20

SQL>
```

---

In your query, those looooong columns: `street_address, postal_code, city, state_province` are the most obvious candidates to be fixed by `col` formatting. Try it.

**Or**: switch to GUI, such as (free) SQL Developer; you'd just scroll left/right and see everything nicely formatted.